# On click export data from database to excel sheet using react

Tags: reactjs, excel

thanks for your support

I am new to react, my task is to implement an onClick event, upon clicking the button it has to download an excel sheet containing data from 2 different tables. I have retrieved data with Axios but not sure on how to export them to an excel sheet. I am able to see the data in the console but how can I export them to excel

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

class getdata extends React.Component{

getData(){

axios.get(`api/getData/${this.id}`)

    .then( response =>{

        console.log(response.data)  
    })
        
    }

render(){

   return(

    <button onclick={this.getData}>Export</button>

   )
  }
}
```

Please help

Comment: This requires the transformation of data into a specific format that excel library accepts, I very recently used sheet.js and exceljs (just today) to achieve the same. wherein excel.js has more features like cell-validation and stuff.

Comment: thanks for the response is there any link that can guide me

Comment: for sheet.js --> https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs

Comment: Yep that worked thanq. but I have one more task, how can I apply colors to the excel rows and columns?